# installing PySide under Kubuntu does not install completely the second time

Tags: python, installation, pyside

I installed pyside under Kubuntu 12.10 the other day using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pyside
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pyside
```

All worked fine then. I tried to move the installed files onto the server into a centralised location which is part of my PYTHONPATH on all machines, but had issues with some host applications afterwards, so I removed those files again and ran this on my local machine:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pyside
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now I'm trying to re-install PySide by starting all over again (s. top). This is the installer's output:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyside
[sudo] password for frank: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-pyside.phonon python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui python-pyside.qthelp python-pyside.qtnetwork python-pyside.qtopengl
  python-pyside.qtscript python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg python-pyside.qttest python-pyside.qtuitools python-pyside.qtwebkit
  python-pyside.qtxml
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pyside python-pyside.phonon python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui python-pyside.qthelp python-pyside.qtnetwork
  python-pyside.qtopengl python-pyside.qtscript python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg python-pyside.qttest python-pyside.qtuitools
  python-pyside.qtwebkit python-pyside.qtxml
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 433 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtgui.
(Reading database ... 126047 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-pyside.qtgui (from .../python-pyside.qtgui_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.phonon.
Unpacking python-pyside.phonon (from .../python-pyside.phonon_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtnetwork.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtnetwork (from .../python-pyside.qtnetwork_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtdeclarative.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtdeclarative (from .../python-pyside.qtdeclarative_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qthelp.
Unpacking python-pyside.qthelp (from .../python-pyside.qthelp_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtopengl.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtopengl (from .../python-pyside.qtopengl_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtscript.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtscript (from .../python-pyside.qtscript_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtsql.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtsql (from .../python-pyside.qtsql_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtsvg.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtsvg (from .../python-pyside.qtsvg_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qttest.
Unpacking python-pyside.qttest (from .../python-pyside.qttest_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtxml.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtxml (from .../python-pyside.qtxml_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtuitools.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtuitools (from .../python-pyside.qtuitools_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.qtwebkit.
Unpacking python-pyside.qtwebkit (from .../python-pyside.qtwebkit_1.1.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyside.
Unpacking python-pyside (from .../python-pyside_1.1.1-3_all.deb) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtgui (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.phonon (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtnetwork (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtdeclarative (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qthelp (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtopengl (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtscript (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtsql (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtsvg (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qttest (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtxml (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtuitools (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside.qtwebkit (1.1.1-3) ...
Setting up python-pyside (1.1.1-3) ...
```

However, the only thing that is installed are some compiled plugins (*.so) in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
No **init**.py inside the package folder etc (like the first time). Naturally I am unable to import PySide.

I am at a loss and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
frank

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to move the installed files onto the server into a centralised location

You can't do that! Well, you can, but on a Linux distribution which gets its programs and utilities installed via a package manager, what you did is just plain wrong.

Your system keeps track of installed files via the package manager. When you manually moved these files to some other location - you severely broke things.

I suspect you have moved other files that were not installed by those pyside packages alone. If you have moved files that were installed via other packages, then you have broken those packages also.

Try completely purging all python-related packages - not just the pyside-related ones - and reinstalling them. And please for the love of all that is good - leave them where the package-maintainer placed them! :)

If you want a custom installation of Python and Pyside, etc. , then your only other option is to download the source code and configure/compile/install from those.

Comment: I only moved the PySide directory and update a symlink exclusive to PySide, so none of the other packages would have been affected. It seems that apt-get is trying to find a dist that doesn't exist. I have compiled PySide myself now and it works.

Comment: Yeah but you still shouldn't move stuff that's been put there by the package. What would happen in the future is that upon a package update/upgrade, the files would just get bunged back in where you moved 'em out from :)

However, you've now compiled PySide yourself, which was a wise move if you're wanting a custom configuration :)